# Perl script stops. Error: Can't find unicode property definition ASCII

Tags: regex, perl, character-properties

I've inherited some perl scripts. (I'm not a perl programmer).

I'm seeing an error `"can't find unicode property definition ascii"` on the below line

```
$value =~ s/[^[:\p{ascii}]]//g
```

Would this error cause the program execution to stop? As it's the last line printed before the program halts.

That same line has been run over 1,000 times before, before it gives up. What can the problem be?

I leaning towards that *the value of $value* is NOT what is causing the problem. *Am I right?*

*It seems to me as though {ascii} has been removed from unicode definitions*. Can this be done *or am I completely barking up the wrong tree?*

Comment: I can't explain your code failing after running for a while, but the regex seems very odd. It matches "anything except '[', ':' or an ASCII Unicode character, followed by ']'. Since '[' and ':' are themselves ASCII Unicode characters, mentioning them at all is superfluous and it makes me think the regex is incorrect. Have you transcribed it incorrectly perhaps? Or if it is accurate, do you know what the pattern is supposed to match?

Comment: And yes, it would cause your program to die unless the error is explicitly caught, which shouldn't be necessary here.

Comment: Looks like a botched conversion from the [traditional POSIX characters class `[[:ascii:]]`](http://p3rl.org/recharclass#POSIX-Character-Classes) to the `\p`/`\P` Perl notation to me.

Comment: tripled checked the line, it is as written.

$value is obtained from an snmp::get command.

I'm guessing it's trying to remove all non ascii characters.

Comment: We have other scripts which are nearly identical, that do not have that line in. I will just remove and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that `ascii` must be uppercase `ASCII`

```
$value =~ s/[^\p{ASCII}]//g
```

**test with \p{ascii}:**

```
#> cat test.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $str = q/☺ùùabvcedhkè ég"/;
$str =~ s/[^\p{ascii}]//g;
print $str,"\n";

#> perl test.pl
Can't find Unicode property definition "ascii" at test.pl line 3.
```

**test with \p{ASCII}:**

```
cat test.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $str = q/☺ùùabvcedhkè ég"/;
$str =~ s/[^\p{ASCII}]//g;
print $str,"\n";

#> perl test.pl
abvcedhk g"
```

Comment: No. From `perldoc perluniprops`: "In parsing these constructs, Perl always ignores Upper/lower case differences everywhere within the {braces}"

Comment: yes I did, and both of your cases work fine on my system (Perl v5.12.3). You may, though, have found the cause of the OP's problem.

Comment: 5.10 appears to be case-sensitive here, but 5.12 and 5.14 aren't.

Comment: @ikegami: Right, as OP didn't say which version he's using, may be it's OK.

Comment: Just saying to which version he needs to upgrade if he wants to continue using lowercase :) (5.10 is no longer supported, fyi)

Comment: we're using 5.10. Till I can get the time to test on the latest version, or rewrite the code.

Strange thing is that code has already been called over 1,000 times before it throws a fit.